# Extracting user input in 2 different arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, user-input

The user input is:

```
7
-3 10
-1 8
-0.5 -1
0.5 1
0.5 -2
0 -5
1 -5
```

And the output I want to get is 2 lists A and B that would print the in the following format:

```
[7, -3, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1]
[10, 8, -1, 1, -2, -5, -5]
```

It would be really helpful if I could get the code for this in python.

Comment: It really depends on how the input is generated, which is why you need to post enough code to replicate the process, otherwise we'd be guessing.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Also don't you think the 7 at the first line indicates the number of lines that follows it ?

Comment: @SurajSubramanian He might be attempting some algo question, I really agree with you that the 7 indicates the number of lines, cuz other languages like Java needs that to initialize an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
INPUT_COUNT = 8

FIRST_INPUTS = []
SECOND_INPUTS = []
for _ in range(INPUT_COUNT):
    result = input().split()
    try:
        FIRST_INPUTS.append(float(result[0]))
        SECOND_INPUTS.append(float(result[1]))
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the basic code for your problem. use space for second input

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

input1, input2 = input().split()
list1.append(int(input1))
list2.append(int(input2))
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

if you need it in some kind of loop then ask for it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./solution.py", line 19, in <module>
    input1, input2 = input().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: yes, I've just noticed it. I didn't account for single input.I'm working on it now